# Arduino C - censoring variable data

Tags: c, arduino

I have two variables:

- dataRx (SLAVE::1234)
- globalAuthcode (1234)

and I comparing

```
     if(strcmp(dataRx, globalAuthcode) == 0)
```

I can't find function like SUBSTR from PHP :) I want leve only 1234 from dataRx variable.

Comment: You should specify the types of these variables. Specifically, if `globalAuthCode` is an integer and not a string, you need to do more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointer arithmetics:

```
strcmp(dataRx + 7, globalAuthcode)
/*           ^^^^ */
```

The `dataRx + 7` skips over the first seven characters of the string. Of course, you might want to make sure that the string *is* at least 7 characters before doing that.

Comment: Cool, thnx :) I can't see this on my tutorial :)

Comment: And how can I leve first X characters? Minus? :)

Comment: @KubaŻukowski If you want only the first seven characters, then you have to copy it to a new buffer, and terminate the string at the seventh character. As for `dataRx + 7`, it's the same as `&dataRx[7]`, which should help you understand why you can't use subtraction (that would be the same as using a negative index in the "array").